# Finding longest sequence of '1's in a binary array by replacing any one '0' with '1'

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have an array which is constituted of only 0s and 1s. Task is to *find index of a 0*, replacing which with a 1 results in the longest possible sequence of ones for the given array. 
Solution has to work within **O(n)** time and **O(1)** space.

*Eg:*

*Array - 011101101001
   
Answer - 4  ( that produces 0111**1**1101001)*

My Approach gives me a result better than O(n2) but times out on long string inputs.

```
int findIndex(int[] a){

    int maxlength = 0; int maxIndex= -1;
    int n=a.length;
    int i=0; 
    while(true){

        if( a[i] == 0 ){
            int leftLenght=0;
            int j=i-1;
            //finding count of 1s to left of this zero
            while(j>=0){
                if(a[j]!=1){
                    break;
                }
                leftLenght++;
                j--;
            }

            int rightLenght=0;
            j=i+1;
            // finding count of 1s to right of this zero
            while(j<n){
                if(a[j]!=1){
                    break;
                }
                rightLenght++;
                j++;
            }

            if(maxlength < leftLenght+rightLenght + 1){
                maxlength = leftLenght+rightLenght + 1;
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        if(i == n-1){
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
```

Comment: What is your code currently? What issues are you having with it?

Comment: Problem with my code is that it is not even close to O(n). It loops over the array multiple times giving me O(n2) performance.

Comment: My first thoughts are to use split to separate the binary string into chunks of 1s only then find the longest pair. String split function is O(n) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/90d6eeed-b7a3-494a-8c90-5035f8465622/algorithm-behind-stringsplit-method?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: What is your thought? share it here and we can help to point you to the correct direction.

Comment: I have an idea how to do this in two array iterations. Walk once to mark and quantify "connected components" (separate sequences of 1), and then walk once more to see which of them sum up to the biggest number. It can be microoptimized by storing information if distance between components is 0 or 1, but it wouldn't improve asymptotic complexity anyway.

Comment: In general, it doesn't sound like a good SO question. It is not even clear which programming language you use and if you use any. If you are looking for algorithmic solution, then it may be a Computer Science question. If you are looking for help with coding, then you are the right place, but in this case you need to share your code and thoughts on it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-software-engin

Comment: what if you treat the 0's as -1's and they actually reduce the total sum. Could you then do a greedy apprach to either take the current sum or the one with the 'change'.

Comment: Also, I tried optimizing my code to take lesser time than O(n2) (PFA this code above)  but it fails with large  inputs on Competitive coding sites. :(

Comment: I've Updated this question with my latest code , please have a look. It runs fine for normal inputs but times out for longer input arrays.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-index-0-replaced-1-get-longest-continuous-sequence-1s-binary-array/ - simpler answer I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is simple, you just need to maintain two numbers while iterating through the array, the current count of the continuous block of one, and the last continuous block of one, which separated by zero.

Note: this solution assumes that there will be at least one zero in the array, otherwise, it will return -1

```java
int cal(int[]data){
    int last = 0;
    int cur = 0;
    int max = 0; 
    int start = -1; 
    int index = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i] == 0){
           if(max < 1 + last + cur){
              max = 1 + last + cur;
              if(start != -1){
                index = start;
              }else{
                index = i;
              }
           }
           last = cur;
           start = i;
           cur = 0;  
        }else{
            cur++;
        }
    }
    if(cur != 0 && start != -1){
       if(max < 1 + last + cur){
          return start;
       }
    }     
    return index;
}
```

O(n) time, O(1) space

Live demo: https://ideone.com/1hjS25

Comment: Counter-test: 1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1

Comment: Thank you, @Pham Trung. I was moving backwards to compute length of 1s. Your solution is saving time on that by keeping it in a separate variable. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem can we solved by just maintaining a variable which stores the last trails of 1's that we saw before reaching a '0'.

```
int last_trail = 0;
int cur_trail = 0;
int last_seen = -1;
int ans = 0, maxVal = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    if(a[i] == '0') {
        if(cur_trail + last_trail + 1 >  maxVal) {
            maxVal = cur_trail + last_trail + 1;
            ans = last_seen;
        }
        last_trail = cur_trail;
        cur_trail = 0;
        last_seen = i; 
    } else {
        cur_trail++;
    }
}
if(cur_trail + last_trail + 1 >  maxVal && last_seen > -1) {
    maxVal = cur_trail + last_trail + 1;
    ans = last_seen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by a technique that is known as [two pointers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-pointers-technique/). Most two-pointers use O(1) space and O(n) time.

Code : https://www.ideone.com/N8bznU

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int findOptimal(string &s) {
    s += '0'; // add a sentinel 0
    int best_zero = -1;
    int prev_zero = -1;
    int zeros_in_interval = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int best_answer = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)s.length(); ++i) {
        if(s[i] == '1') continue;
        else if(s[i] == '0' and  zeros_in_interval == 0) {
            zeros_in_interval++;
            prev_zero = i;
        }
        else if(s[i] == '0' and zeros_in_interval == 1) {
            int curr_answer =  i - start; // [start, i) only contains one 0
            cout << "tried this : [" << s.substr(start, i - start) << "]\n";
            if(curr_answer > best_answer) {
                best_answer = curr_answer;
                best_zero = prev_zero;
            }
            start = prev_zero + 1;
            prev_zero = i;
        }
    }
    cout << "Answer = " << best_zero << endl;
    return best_zero;
}
int main() {
    string input = "011101101001";
    findOptimal(input);
    return 0;
}
```

This is an implementation in C++. The output looks like this:

```
tried this : [0111]
tried this : [111011]
tried this : [1101]
tried this : [10]
tried this : [01]
Answer = 4
```